# В чем разница использований асинхронных и неасинхронных лямбда-выражений в Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Насколько мне известно **Task.Run** отдает задачу потоку взятому из пула, для выполнения этой самой задачи. Но в чем разница между

Этим

```
Task.Run(() => SomeAsyncTaskMethod());
```

и этим

```
Task.Run(async () => await SomeAsyncTaskMethod());
```

В первом случае всё понятно, мы просто отдаем другому потоку выполнение таска, а активный поток продолжает идти дальше по коду. Но что происходит во втором случае? Как я понимаю подобные конструкции нужны для более сложных задач, где нужна последовательность выполнения методов, но зачем писать это, если в таком случае можно запускать внутри лямбды еще один таск, ведь без этого - не важно есть await или нет, метод будет выполнен синхронно.

И так же что происходит с потоком? Выделенный поток становится в ожидание и отдает управление другому потоку, или как?

Этот вопрос у меня возник по той простой причине, что если мы напишем в каком-нибудь асинхронном методе следующее:

```
// Представим, что этот код лежит в каком-нибудь async методе
...
await Task.Run(() => AnotherOneMethod());
...
```

то активный поток, когда увидит оператор await просто отдаст задачу другому потоку, а сам уйдет обратно в тот код(в моем случае Main), который вызвал сам метод.

И при всём при этом если мы используем `await Task.Run(async () => await SomeAsyncTaskMethod());` то он будет выполнятся на одном потоке который был взят и пула. В чем же тогда смысл использовать в этом месте асинхронное лямбда выражение, если всё будет работать ровно так же? Этот вопрос у меня возникает не сколько от непонимания как это работает, сколько от непонимания зачем в огромном количестве примеров использования async\await пишут подобные конструкции.

Я понимаю, что в сфере асинхронного программирования знаний у меня еще недостаточно, я могу ошибаться в терминологии, так что было бы неплохо, если бы мне в случае чего разъяснили в каких моментах я не прав или дали ру-статью о тасках и асинхроне в шарпе в целом

Comment: _знаний у меня еще недостаточно_ - у большинства знаний недостаточно. Вот и пишут как попало. То async приткнут, то await добавят...

Comment: Теоретически это всё интересно, но на практике в асинхронном методе вы можете просто написать `await AnotherOneMethod();` зачем вам там нужен `Task.Run` - решительно непонятно. Ну, разве что вы целенаправленно хотите увести этот вызов в другой поток - например, вы хотите выполнить что-то долгое из `UI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться, нужно понять, что такое лямбда на логическом уровне.

`() => MethodAsync()` где метод возращает `Task` это

```
Task MethodAsync()
{
    return MethodAsync();
}
```

`async () => await MethodAsync()` где метод возвращает `Task` это

```
async Task LambdaAsync()
{
    await MethodAsync();
}
```

В данном конкретном случае используется `Func<Task>` или `Func<Task<T>>`, в зависимости от того, что возвращает сам асинхронный метод метод - `Task` или `Task<T>`.

И здесь важный момент - первый вариант ЛУЧШЕ второго по той простой причине что он является его оптимизированной версией, а работают логически они оба совершенно ОДИНАКОВО.

Оптимизация заключается в том, что для `async` метода компилятор генерирует достаточно сложную обвязку - машину состояний. А зачем нам машина состояний, в которой всего-лишь одно полезное состояние? В этом случае эффективным решением является избавление от `async`.

Такая оптимизация может применена в любом методе, не только в лямбдах, а условия следующие:

- Внутри `async` метода всего-лишь один `await`
- `await` стоит перед хвостовым методом, то есть после метода с `await` ничего в коде не написано
- `await` не является частью конструкции `try-catch-finally` (напомню, конструкция `using` для `IDisposable` порождает `try-finally`)

Вот и получается, что оба ваши `Task.Run` - одинаковые логически.

---

Теперь про потоки. Вы пытаетесь разобраться с системой ожидания (асинхронностью) с помощью рассуждения о потоках (многопоточности). Здесь есть подвох - это разные, никак не связанные между собой механизмы. Многие их путают или смешивают, это грубая ошибка в рассуждениях, которая ведет к очевидно ошибочным выводам.

Чтобы понять как система ожидания `async/await` взаимодействует с потоками, надо знать внутреннее устройство контекста синхронизации. А точнее именно текущего контекста синхронизации. В UI приложениях типа Winforms или WPF используется однопоточный контекст синхронизации, в консольном приложении он отсутствует, то есть используется контекст синхронизации по умолчанию.

Подробнее можно с этим разобраться взглянув на логику выполнения `async` метода, на примере вот этого псевдокода:

```
async
{
    // начало
    await
    // продолжение
    await
    // продолжение
}
```

Здесь "начало" всегда выполняется в потоке вызывающего метода, а "продолжение" - в потоке, в который его поместил текущий контекст синхронизации. Если контекста нет, то есть `SynchronizationContext.Current` возвращает `null`, тогда "продолжение" [выполняется на пуле потоков](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/SynchronizationContext.cs#L22)

```
public virtual void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object? state)
    => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(static s => s.d(s.state), (d, state), preferLocal: false);
```

В вашем же случае продолжения никакого нет (оно есть, там технический `return task;` но будем считать что нет), а следовательно контекст синхронизации не играет никакой роли и разницы при выполнении первого и второго вариантов лямбд нет.

---

По изложенному выше, так как `Task.Run` предназначен для выполнения его делегата на пуле потоков, то да, независимо от того, синхронная у вас лямбда или асинхронная - она будет выполнена потоком из пула.

Но будьте осторожны с асинхронными лямбдами, никогда не делайте так `async => Method()`, то есть не используйте асинхронные лябды без `await`. В большинстве случаев у вас получится `async void` лямбда и ожидания ее выполнения не произойдет, как и захвата вероятного исключения внутри нее. Например:

```
// ПЛОХОЙ КОД, НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК
await Task.Run(async () => Task.Delay(1000));
```

Здесь ожидания в 1 секунду не произойдет, так как лямбда будет типа `async Task<Task>`. То есть чтобы этот код исправить, в чем особого смысла нет, то надо написать так

```
var task = await Task.Run(async () => Task.Delay(1000));
await task;
```

Поэтому будьте внимательны, не используйте `async` без `await`.

При этом вот эти 2 варианта отработают корректно:

```
await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));
```

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
```

Comment: `() => Method()` - это скорее `MethodReturnType Lambda() { return Method(); }`

Comment: c async/await та же логика в примере

Comment: @Grundy в отношении к перегрузкам `Task.Run` - да. Но вы написали это замечание не прочитав ответ дальше.

Comment: это применимо именно к лямбдам

Comment: @Grundy подправил ответ

Comment: вот про это `async () => await MethodAsync() где метод возвращает Task это` скорее всего неверно, так как `await Task` так и останется `Task` а не `void`. Но есть не выйдет `async void`

Comment: @Grundy `await Task` это `void`, попробуйте `var x = await Task.CompletedTask;`, не скомпилится.

Comment: `async Task !== async void`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140864/discussion-between-grundy-and-aepot).

Comment: @Grundy `!==` - лови фронтендера! :)

Comment: @aepot Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! 
По оптимизации: Представим, что у нас есть сервер, в котором бесконечно крутятся некоторые инструкции
`var connection = await GetNewConnection(); ` - ожидает нового соединения клиента к серверу;
и `Process(connection);` - метод `async Task`, у которого будет свой цикл для работы с подключением (например, валидация и общение). Этот метод вызывается для каждого клиента.

Так вот, каким образом мне правильнее будет вызывать этот метод? Объявлять новый таск, или использовать статический, или вообще вызывать как есть?

Comment: @Priest_ по частным случаям лучше смотреть конкретный код. Но в рамках текущего вопроса нужно просто было разобраться, что из себя представляет асинхронная лямбда. Не используйте `Task.Run` для асинхронных методов вообще. Асинхронный метод не требует выделения потока, за выделение потоков в асинхронных операциях отвечает контекст синхронизации, не следует от этого поведения избавляться выпрыгивая принудительно в пул потоков.