# Что лучше Task.FromResult или async без await?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

Что лучше использовать для методов где нет await ?

```
public Task<int> Meth1()
{
   return Task.FromResult(5);
}

public async Task<int> Meth2()
{
  return 5;
}
```

Comment: А смысл что-то из этого использовать?

Comment: Впрочем, подозреваю, что FromResult лучше.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну например реализовываем интерфейс и предполагаем что в будущем возможно будет await или в других реализациях будет

Comment: Вы не понимаете что такое асинхронность. Прочитайте [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1416840/422180) ответ. `async-await` - всего лишь сахар позволяющий *дождаться* выполнения и получить результат какой-то асинхронной функции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` без `await` использовать нет смысла. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250886/373567).

`async` генерит из метода машину состояний, но какой в ней смысл, если у нее всего одно состояние? Я скажу больше, что даже имея один `await` в [некоторых случаях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1471301/373567) можно избавиться от `async`.

Поэтому из предложенных вариантов `Task.FromResult` выглядит оптимальнее.

Comment: А если метод в дальнейшем точно планируется сделать асинхронным, с каким-то асинхронным функционалом с `await`, а пока у нас только заготовка, нет ли смысла использовать второй вариант, только добавить туда `await Task.CompletedTask;` в качестве заглушки, чтобы компилятор не предупреждал, что отсутствует `await` и поэтому `async` не нужен? )  Я просто сталкивался с такими ситуациями и до сих пор не совсем понимаю, правильно ли так делать.

Comment: @CrazyElf `await Task.CompletedTask;` это для методов типа `Task<Task>`? Ни разу не видел таких, вы что-то перепутали. А так, каждый пишет так как ему удобнее. Не вижу никаких проблем добавить модификатор `async` методу при первой необходимости.

Comment: Нет, это для просто `Task`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096253/await-task-completedtask-for-what  Хорошо, если выше по цепочке всё уже асинхронное, а если нет? Конечно, могут быть разные подходы к проектированию, но если есть возможность, почему бы не подготовиться заранее.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну так там return а не await

Comment: в целом интересно насколько это "жирная" операция сгенерить стейт машину ?

Comment: @Greg9303 не жирная, но зачем делать то, в чем нет необходимости?